# How to hide items visibility from "Menu Visibility" or "Tool Bar Visibility" menu, from "Customize Perspective" option (programmatically)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have created an eclipse plugin perspective layout, which is working fine, but now I need to hide the items visibility from "Menu Visibility" or "Tool Bar Visibility" menu, from "Customize Perspective" option, (programmatically), so the items will be hidden by default. How to do this?

So far I have the java class implementation for the Perspective:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {

    String editor = layout.getEditorArea();

            IFolderLayout left = layout.createFolder(AREA_NAME_1, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.2f, editor);
            left.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT);

            IFolderLayout left = layout.createFolder(AREA_NAME_2, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, AREA_1);
            left.addView("org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView");

            IFolderLayout right = layout.createFolder(AREA_NAME_3, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.5f, editor);
            right.addView("org.eclipse.debug.ui.VariableView");

            IFolderLayout right = layout.createFolder(AREA_NAME_4, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.4f, AREA_2);
            right.addView(IPageLayout.ID_OUTLINE);

            layout.addActionSet("org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet");
}
```

and the plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            id="com.ultrasoc.ui.perspectives.Name"
            name="Name"
            icon="platform:/plugin/com.plugin.core/icons/name.png"
            class="com.plugin.ui.perspectives.Name">
      </perspective>      
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hide what items?

Comment: Hi @greg-449 Lets say I need to have unticked "Action Set Availability" by default from: Windows > Perspective > Customize Perspective... > Action Set Availability. How to programmatically set that option ticked or unticked

Comment: As far as I can see all the code to do that is in internal classes and therefore should not be used.

Comment: @greg-449 Ok, I was thinking if it would be possible to override the value of the options somehow (isVisible().. or something like that) but you you recommend not to touch internal classes, correct? Do you think there is an alternative way? a workaround to approach this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Internal code is explicitly off limits see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html), Internal code may change at any time.

Comment: I am also interested in it. @MELS Have you found any solution ?